# How can I use the Player gameobject in two scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a main menu scene and game scene. The Load button is in the main menu and the script with the load/save functions is on the Player that is in the game scene.

I can't even drag the Player to the onclick button event in the main menu since it's not in the same scene.

[image: Editor]

On the Player in the Game scene I have this script attached :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SavePlayer()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
    }

    public void LoadPlayer()
    {
        PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();

        Vector3 position;
        position.x = data.position[0];
        position.y = data.position[1];
        position.z = data.position[2];
        transform.position = position;

        Quaternion rotation;
        rotation.x = data.rotation[0];
        rotation.y = data.rotation[1];
        rotation.z = data.rotation[2];
        rotation.w = data.rotation[3];
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

And in the Main Menu Load button I have one onclick event for the button load dialogue :

```
public void MouseClick(string buttonType)
        {
            if (buttonType == "Controls")
            {
                controlsMenu.SetActive(true);
                menuNumber = 6;
            }

            if (buttonType == "Graphics")
            {
                GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
                graphicsMenu.SetActive(true);
                menuNumber = 3;
            }

            if (buttonType == "Sound")
            {
                GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
                soundMenu.SetActive(true);
                menuNumber = 4;
            }

            if (buttonType == "Exit")
            {
                Debug.Log("YES QUIT!");
                Application.Quit();
            }

            if (buttonType == "Options")
            {
                menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
                GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(true);
                menuNumber = 2;
            }

            if (buttonType == "LoadGame")
            {
                menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
                loadGameDialog.SetActive(true);
                menuNumber = 8;
            }

            if (buttonType == "NewGame")
            {
                menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
                newGameDialog.SetActive(true);
                menuNumber = 7;
            }
        }
```

This is from a script in the main menu that control the buttons.
I need this event to have the dialogue if to load yes/no back options.

So I want to add on the same load button another onclick event for the LoadPlayer function.
but the LoadPlayer script is attached to the Player in the Game scene so I don't have access to the LoadPlayer function.

I can make the Player object to be DontDestroyOnLoad but still how do I get a reference to the Load button onclick event ?

Ok so in the main menu when clicking the Load Game button I'm loading the "Game" scene :

```
public void ClickLoadGameDialog(string ButtonType)
        {
            if (ButtonType == "Yes")
            {
                newGameDialog.SetActive(false);
            
      StartCoroutine(sceneFader.FadeAndLoadScene(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, _newGameButtonLevel)); 
            }

            if (ButtonType == "No")
            {
                GoBackToMainMenu();
            }
        }
```

but I also need to call the LoadPlayer function to apply the changes in the Game scene. Then maybe I don't need another onclick event but how to get a reference to the Player object ?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can make the player a prefab?

Comment: See this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/no-more-cross-scene-references.530109/

Answer (score 0):

and easy way to do it is the next.
You have your SaveSystem.LoadPlayer is an static function, you need an event static in SaveSystem
using System;
public static event Action LoadPlayerDataEvent;
In Player Script you change the load player to

```
void OnEnable(){
     SaveSystem.LoadPlayerDataEvent += LoadPlayer;
}
void OnDisable(){
     SaveSystem.LoadPlayerDataEvent -= LoadPlayer;
}
```

Then in your ClickLoadGameDialog just launch the event with this SaveSystem.LoadPlayerDataEvent?.Invoke();